# Save embedded HSQL database to file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

For logging and debugging purposes I want to dump an embedded/in-memory HSQL database to a file. Schema + Data. I'm using the spring-framework with hibernate.

I've tried both:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.createSQLQuery("BACKUP DATABASE TO '/tmp/backup.tar.gz' BLOCKING");

    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
```

and

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    session.createSQLQuery("SCRIPT '/tmp/backup-data.sql'");

    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
```

Both to no avail.

There is no special configuration.

#### Hibernate config:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:spring/batch/database/schema.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain.*.model"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.format_sql=true
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What did I miss, do I need a different approach, is it even possible?

Comment: You are only creating the query, not executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is only creating an instance of a `SQLQuery` and throws it away. You aren't executing the query.

Add/change to the following

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("BACKUP DATABASE TO '/tmp/backup.tar.gz' BLOCKING");
query.executeUpdate();
```

This will execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

session.createSQLQuery("BACKUP DATABASE TO '/tmp/' BLOCKING");

transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

According to the [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_backup) you need to give the directory and HSQL will create the tar.gz file in it.

Comment: Yes I have also tried this. And again just now to be sure ;) This does not work for me either.